# Adjective for this kind of personality

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What's a word for someone who likes the finer things in life - classy taste, but makes do and replicates that expensive taste with cheap things?

Comment: ...... typical? (taking 'cheap' to mean 'less expensive' rather than 'trashy')

Comment: Realistic? Responsible? Normal? Average? Intelligent? Unaffected? Budget-conscious? Or are you looking for a negative word, and if so, why? Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1):

While not limited to affecting expensive trappings, the term **[poseur](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/poseur)** (or **poser**) is often used to mean

> a person who assumes attitudes or manners merely for their effect upon others

It also may not reflect a true appreciation for quality, but merely the impression it conveys.

[Collins American Dictionary]

A related concept is **veneer of respectability**.  One of [Macmillan's](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/veneer) definitions of *veneer* is

> a pleasant appearance, or a polite way of behaving that is not sincere: 
>   *a veneer of respectability*

Again, this is not limited to luxury goods.

Answer (score 0):

*Cheapskate* implies someone who always find ways to pay less or as little as possible, but does not imply poor, and would often be used towards someone who has means, but still wants to spend like a *tightarse*.